# Swing: How do I run a job from AWT thread, but after a window was layed out?

Tags: java, multithreading, events, swing, awt

My complete GUI runs inside the AWT thread, because I start the main window using `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(...)`.

Now I have a JDialog which has just to display a `JLabel`, which indicates that a certain job is in progress, and close that dialog after the job was finished.

**The problem is: the label is not displayed. That job seems to be started before `JDialog` was fully layed-out.**

When I just let the dialog open without waiting for a job and closing, the label *is* displayed.

The last thing the dialog does in its ctor is `setVisible(true)`.
Things such as `revalidate()`, `repaint()`, ... don't help either.

Even when I start a thread for the monitored job, and wait for it using `someThread.join()` it doesn't help, because the current thread (which is the AWT thread) is blocked by `join`, I guess.

Replacing `JDialog` with `JFrame` doesn't help either.

**So, is the concept wrong in general? Or can I manage it to do certain job *after* it is ensured that a `JDialog` (or `JFrame`) is fully layed-out?**

Simplified algorithm of what I'm trying to achieve:

- Create a subclass of `JDialog`
- Ensure that it and its contents are fully layed-out
- Start a process and wait for it to finish (threaded or not, doesn't matter)
- Close the dialog

I managed to write a **reproducible** test case:

**EDIT** Problem from an answer is now addressed:
This use case **does** display the label, but it fails to close
after the "simulated process", because of dialog's modality.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class _DialogTest2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            final JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("Please wait...");
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Main frame");
                myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                myFrame.setSize(750, 500);
                myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                myFrame.setVisible(true);

                JDialog d = new JDialog(myFrame, "I'm waiting");
                d.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

                d.add(jLabel);
                d.setSize(300, 200);
                d.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                d.setVisible(true);

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(3000); // simulate process
                            jLabel.setText("Done");
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                    }
                });

                d.setVisible(false);
                d.dispose();

                myFrame.setVisible(false);
                myFrame.dispose();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code segment where you initiate your swing components.

Comment: I don't really get what the problem is. If you application runs inside a Thread, well you simply can display you JDialog from it, then launch your job (also from the thread) with using the JDialog as a parameter of the job. Something like this:
JDialog myDialog = ....;
launchMyJob(myDialog);
When the process is complete, close the JDialog from the job.

For you label problem, as Amjad said, you should show how you instantiate your JDialog and its components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
package javaapplication3;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception {
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

        final JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("Please wait...");

        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Main frame");
            myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            myFrame.setSize(750, 500);
            myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            myFrame.setVisible(true);

            JDialog d = new JDialog(myFrame, "I'm waiting");

            d.add(jLabel);
            d.setSize(300, 200);
            d.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            d.setVisible(true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000); // simulate process
                        jLabel.setText("Done");   // HERE: should be done on EDT!
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                }
            }).start();


        }
    });
}
}
```

This one works, but it's not correct. I'll explain whats going on.

Your `main()` method starts out in 'main' thread. All Swing related code should be done on EDT thread. And this is why You are using (correctly) `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(...)`. So far so good.

But there should be no long running tasks on EDT. Since Swing is single threaded any long running processes will block the EDT. So your code `Thread.wait(...)` should never be executed on EDT. And this is my modification. I wrapped the invocation in another thread. So this is idiomatic long running task handling for Swing. I used Thread class for brevity, but I'd really recommend going with `SwingWorker` thread.

And very important: I'm making one error in preceding example. See the line with "HERE" comment? This is another Swing one-thread rule violation. Code inside the thread is running *outside* EDT, so it should never touch Swing. So this code is not a correct with Swing one-thread rule. It's not safe from freezing GUI.

How to correct this? Simple. You should wrap your call in another thread and put it on EDT queue. So correct code should look like:

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                jLabel.setText("Done");
            }
        });
```

**EDIT**: This question is touching a lot Swing related issues. Can't explain them all at once... But here is one more snippet, which does what You want:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception {
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

        final JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Main frame");
        final JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("Please wait...");
        final JDialog d = new JDialog(myFrame, "I'm waiting");

        @Override
        public void run() {
            myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            myFrame.setSize(750, 500);
            myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            myFrame.setVisible(true);

            d.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

            d.add(jLabel);
            d.setSize(300, 200);
            d.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000); // simulate process
                        System.out.println("After");
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {


                                d.setVisible(false);
                                d.dispose();

                                myFrame.setVisible(false);
                                myFrame.dispose();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            d.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}
```

To sum up:

- All Swing related code must run on EDT
- All long running code must not run on EDT
- Code can be run on EDT using `SwingUtilities.`...

  - `invokeAndWait()` - as the name says, call is synchronous,
  - `invokeLater()` - invoke the code 'sometime', but return immediately
- If you are on EDT and want to invoke code on another thread, than you can:

  - Create a new `Thread` (pass a Runnable to new Thread or override it's `start()` method) and start it ,
  - Create a new `SwingWorker` thread which has some extras.
  - Possibly use any other threading mechanism (for example Executor threads).

The typical GUI scenario involves:

1. Creating GUI components,
2. Wiring up property change listeners,
3. Executing code related to user actions (i.e. running property change listeners),
4. Running possibly time consuming tasks,
5. Updating GUI state,

1., 2., 3. and 4. run on *EDT*. 4. should not. There are many ways to write proper threading code. The most cumbersome is using `Thread` class which came with early versions of Java. If one does it naively, resources can be wasted (too many threads runnning at once). Also updating GUI is cumbersome. Using SwingWorker is alleviates the problem a little. It's guaranteed to behave properly while starting, running and updating GUI (each has a dedicated method which you can override and be sure it runs on proper thread).

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is now: my dialog is modal, so it never closes after process ended. Please see updated test case in my question.

Comment: Yeah, it's quite a complicated problem. I'm posting my answer one part at a time.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed explanations!

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the previous answers you MUST run the lengthy job in a thread DIFFERENT from the EDT.

The easiest IMHO is to use a SwingWorker and add a listener to dispose the dialog when finished. Here's a sample:

SwingWorkerCompletionWaiter.java

```
public class SwingWorkerCompletionWaiter implements PropertyChangeListener {
  private JDialog dialog;

  public SwingWorkerCompletionWaiter(JDialog dialog) {
      this.dialog = dialog;
  }

  @Override
  public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
      if ("state".equals(event.getPropertyName())
              && SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE == event.getNewValue()) {
          dialog.setVisible(false);
          dialog.dispose();
      }
  }
}
```

And the following code will run some lengthy task:

```
SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    // do something long
  }
};
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    // initialize the dialog here
worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new SwingWorkerCompletionWaiter(dialog));
worker.execute();
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

And if you want to create some sort of "Please wait" dialog it might be easier to just extend JDialog and use the extended class everywhere you need to.

Comment: Thank you, a listener is a nice idea!

Answer (score 0):

First, sorry fo speculating about the job thing, I didn't really understood what you were trying to do before you posted your code.

Nevertheless, I'm not really familliar with this way of creating dialogs and windows and general, so I suggest that you create a separate class for your JDialog. Just a simple class, something like this:

```
public class MyDialog extends JDialog
{
    public MyDialog(JFrame owner, String title)
    {
        super(owner, title);

        d.setSize(300, 200);           
        d.setLocationRelativeTo(null);           
        d.setVisible(true);
        d.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );

        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        c.add(new JLabel("Please wait..."));  
    }
}
```

And launch the dialog this way:

```
new MyDialog(this, "Your title");
```

It would maybe look like shit, but it may work (I have not tested).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, my problem is clearly related to threading issues of the AWT thread, because without waiting for that background job, everything is displayed correctly, as I states in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the job in a background thread or the main application thread. The JDialog and JFrame should be created on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater();`. Then wait until the job finishes and close the dialog in the (EDT). Since the layouting and the job are on two separate threads, there should be no problem. In fact the following modification of your example works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Main frame");
    final JDialog d = new JDialog(myFrame, "I'm waiting");

    final Thread backgroundJob = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000); // simulate process
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
    });
    backgroundJob.start();

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            myFrame.setSize(750, 500);
            myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            myFrame.setVisible(true);

            d.add(new JLabel("Please wait..."));
            d.setSize(300, 200);
            d.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            d.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    backgroundJob.join();

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            d.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Sadly, my background job is doing GUI-related work, so it can't be outside the AWT-thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should use invokeLater insteadof InvokeAndWait.

```
public class DialogTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final JLabel comp =  new JLabel("the job has started");;
        final JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Main frame");
        final JDialog d = new JDialog(myFrame, "I'm waiting");
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                myFrame.setSize(750, 500);
                myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                myFrame.setVisible(true);

                 d.setModalityType(JDialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL); 
                d.add(comp);
                d.setSize(300, 200);
                d.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                d.setVisible(true);


            }
        });
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            // d.setVisible(false);     
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    comp.setText("the job has finished");
                     d.setVisible(false);         
                     d.dispose();         
                     myFrame.setVisible(false);         
                     myFrame.dispose(); 
                }
            });

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Sadly, in the real case I am fighting with I can't do such solution for some reasons.