# Thread issue in java

Tags: java

I've made a chat app and it's using server and client to communicate.
on the server GUI i've made a "start" button which should run the server by calling a thread.
my problem is when i click the "start" button another window of GUI starts instead of just updating the old GUI window and start the server.

here's my code:

the thread code:

```
public class SerTest implements Runnable{
@Override
public void run(){
    Server serv = new Server();
    serv.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    serv.startRunning();
        }
```

the button listener code:

```
 start_server.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            (new Thread((Runnable) new SerTest())).start();
        }
    });
```

[image: in the image you can see what i mean:]

Comment: Absolutely expected behavior as to the given code! In your button-click-handler you make a new instance of the SerTest class which in turn creates a new instance of the Server class which seems to be the gui and starts it ...

Comment: why are you creating a new SerTest object inside the actionListener? Secondly is a new window created when you create a object of SerTest class?

Comment: Why does your **server** have a gui in the first place? That makes things more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to do in actionPerformed assuming you are calling this code in SerTest to begin with.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //don't allow user to start server when it's already running
    //should add something to re-enable this button for when the
    //server stops.
    ((JButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);

    //create new Thread pointing Runnable to this instance of SerTest
    new Thread(SerTest.this).start();
}
```

Although I don't use Swing at all. I don't think you are allowed to set stuff on another thread. I believe it must all be run on the [Swing event handler thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537626/swing-how-do-i-run-a-job-from-awt-thread-but-after-a-window-was-layed-out). I am referring to `serv.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` which is in your Runnable.